Is my `processPurchase` method correctly charging customer accounts in Java?
I have a piece of code in Java that processes purchases for different types of customers (StudentCustomer, StaffCustomer, and a generic Customer). Each customer type has a different way of charging their account. I want to make sure that the processPurchase method is correctly charging the accounts based on the customer type. Here's the code:
public void processPurchase(String customerId, String snackId) throws InvalidPurchaseException, Customer.InvalidCustomerException, Snack.InvalidSnackException, Customer.InsufficientBalanceException {
    Customer customer = getCustomer(customerId);
    Snack snack = getSnack(snackId);
    int price = snack.calculatePrice();
    int finalPrice ;
    if (customer instanceof StudentCustomer studentCustomer) {
        finalPrice = studentCustomer.chargeAccount(price);
    } else if (customer instanceof StaffCustomer staffCustomer) {
        finalPrice = staffCustomer.chargeAccount(price);
    } else {
        finalPrice= customer.chargeAccount(price);
    }

    totalSales += finalPrice;
}

public class StaffCustomer extends Customer {
    // attributes
    private final String school;

    // constructor
    public StaffCustomer(String accountId, String name, String school) throws InvalidCustomerException {
        super(accountId, name);
        this.school = school;
    }

    public StaffCustomer(String accountId, String name, int balance, String school) throws InvalidCustomerException {
        super(accountId, name, balance);
        this.school = school;
    }

    //methods
    @Override
    public int chargeAccount(int snackPrice) throws InsufficientBalanceException {
        double discount = 0;
        switch (school) {
            case "CMP":
                discount = 0.10;
                break;
            case "MTH":
            case "BIO":
                discount = 0.02;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        // find the discount based on the school
        double discountedPrice = snackPrice * (1 - discount);
        // round up the discounted price
        if (getBalance() < discountedPrice) {
            // if the balance is less than the final price
            throw new InsufficientBalanceException("Insufficient balance");
            // throw an exception
        }
        this.balance -= (int) discountedPrice;
        // Subtract the final price from the balance
        return (int) discountedPrice;
        // return the final price
    }

    // toString method
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StaffCustomer{" +
                "AccountId='" + getAccountId() + '\'' +
                ", Name='" + getName() + '\'' +
                ", Balance=" + getBalance() +
                ", School='" + school + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}


public class StudentCustomer extends Customer {
    // attributes
    private static final double StudentDiscount = 0.05;
    private static final int AllowedCredit = -500;

    // constructor
    public StudentCustomer(String accountId, String name) throws InvalidCustomerException {
        super(accountId, name);
    }

    public StudentCustomer(String accountId, String name, int balance) throws InvalidCustomerException {
        super(accountId, name, balance);
    }

    //methods
    @Override
    public int chargeAccount(int snackPrice) throws InsufficientBalanceException {
        double discount = StudentDiscount;
        // get the discount
        double discountedPrice = snackPrice * (1 - discount);
        // round up the discounted price
        if (getBalance() < discountedPrice) {
            // if the balance is less than the final price
            if (getBalance() < AllowedCredit) {
                throw new InsufficientBalanceException("Insufficient balance");
            }
        }
        this.balance -= (int) discountedPrice;
        // Subtract the final price from the balance
        return (int) discountedPrice;
        // return the final price
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StudentCustomer{" +
                "AccountId='" + getAccountId() + '\'' +
                ", Name='" + getName() + '\'' +
                ", Balance=" + getBalance() +
                '}';
    }

    public static double getDiscountAmount() {
        return StudentDiscount;
    }
}

public class Customer {
    //attributes

    //most likely they are not going to be changed, making them final
    private final String accountId;
    private final String name;
    protected int balance;



    // Exception class
    public static class InvalidCustomerException extends Exception {
        public InvalidCustomerException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    public static class InsufficientBalanceException extends Exception {
        public InsufficientBalanceException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
    //constructors
    public Customer(String accountId, String name) throws InvalidCustomerException {
        if (accountId.length() != 6) {
            // if the account ID is not 6 characters long, throw an exception
            throw new InvalidCustomerException("Invalid account ID");
        }
        this.accountId = accountId;
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = 0;
    }

    public Customer(String accountId, String name, int balance) throws InvalidCustomerException {
        this(accountId, name);
        if (balance < 0) {
            // if the balance is negative, throw an exception
            throw new InvalidCustomerException("Negative balance is not allowed");
        }
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    //accessors
    public String getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    //mutators
    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }


    //methods
    public void addFunds(int amount) {
        if (amount > 0) {
            this.balance += amount;
            // if the amount is positive, add it to the balance
        }
    }

    public int chargeAccount(int snackPrice) throws InsufficientBalanceException {
        if (snackPrice > this.balance) {

            throw new InsufficientBalanceException("Insufficient balance");
            // if the snack price is greater than the balance, throw an exception
        }
        this.balance -= snackPrice;
        // if the snack price is less than the balance, subtract it from the balance
        return snackPrice;
    }
}
'''


when my main is run it seems like the accounts arent being charged right as, the total sales are too high and the wrong amount of negative accounts are shown


Please provide a [mre]. With the code you included in your question, all we are able to tell you is that you correctly check for the type of Customer and call the corresponding chargeAccount() method. We'd need at least the code of Customer, StudentCustomerand StaffCustomer.

that said, I don't see why you can't simply do totalSales += customer.chargeAccount(price); and let polymorphism do its thing (no if statements at all). If the customer is an instance of any of those classes, it will call the #chargeAccount of that relevant type. This assumes that StudentCustomer extends Customer and StaffCustomer extends Customer.

i have added the the missing classes thank you

Instead of checking for each instance you can override the method that removes cash from each type of customer. Here is an example of how this can work:
public class Customer {
    int balance;

    public Customer(int balance){
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    protected void chargeAccount(int productPrice){
        removeFromBalance(productPrice);
    };

    protected void removeFromBalance(int amount){
        this.balance -= amount;
    }
}

Then create a different kind of customer and override the way they are charged:
public class StudentCustomer extends Customer{
    public StudentCustomer(int balance){
        super(balance);
    }

    @Override
    protected void chargeAccount(int productPrice) {
        //example : Student has 5$ reduction in price
        removeFromBalance(productPrice - 5 );
    }
}

This way, you only need to call the chargeAccount() method without checking for the instance of the class yourself:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer student = new StudentCustomer(100);
        Customer simpleCustomer = new Customer(100);

        int snack_cost = 10;

        student.chargeAccount(snack_cost);
        simpleCustomer.chargeAccount(snack_cost);

        System.out.println("Student balance: " + student.balance);
        System.out.println("Simple Customer balance: " + simpleCustomer.balance);
    }
}


